# CartoDB - Method to show/hide layers for hatching overlap for > 4 layers?

Tags: carto, visualisation, overlay

Our goal is to show/hide individual hatched maps.
Unfortunately we have more than the 4 max layers allowed in a viz. 
We successfully made and example where we show/hide the 4 layers in a viz:
http://maps.massgis.state.ma.us/cartodb_test/cartodb_demo_1_viz_show_hide_animals_chkbox_legend.html

Next, we tried to have an example where we have 2 viz, each with 4 layers and try to show/hide all 8 items on the map.  They all draw on the map at first and clear, but then the show/hide doesn't properly work. We tried two methods:

1) Try to put the second viz into a different objects called layers2
http://maps.massgis.state.ma.us/cartodb_test/cartodb_2_viz_show_hide_animals_chkbox_method1.html
2) Try to put the second viz into the same layers object
http://maps.massgis.state.ma.us/cartodb_test/cartodb_2_viz_show_hide_animals_chkbox_method2.html

Is there a way to combine > 1 viz with > 1 layer each and do show/hide.  Alternatively, we could have 1 layer per viz and show/hide each viz somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I've been debugging your code. Apart from some syntax error, the problem was that you we're using "local" layer variables, instead of ""global"".

Also, I've 'concatenate in cascade mode' the queries.

I'm attaching the solution. (Please, note that perhaps layers aren't linked layer<->animal correctly) But it's the method that you need to use.

Also, I would like to recommend you that you don't use "checkboxes" with *Clear all*, because it's a bit strange and no usability.

```
 <script>

    var layers_0;
    var layers_1;

  function createSelector(layers) {
    var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'documentation' });
    var $options = $('#layer_selector li');

    $("#Clear_Check").change(function() {
      var value = $(this).prop("checked") ? 'true' : 'false';
      if (value == "true") {
        layers_1.getSubLayer(0).hide();
        layers_1.getSubLayer(1).hide();
        layers_1.getSubLayer(2).hide();
        layers_1.getSubLayer(3).hide();

        layers_0.getSubLayer(0).hide();
        layers_0.getSubLayer(1).hide();
        layers_0.getSubLayer(2).hide();
        layers_0.getSubLayer(3).hide();
      }
    });

    $("#Cats_Check").change(function() {
        var value = $(this).prop("checked") ? 'true' : 'false';
        if (value == "true") {
            layers_0.getSubLayer(0).show(); 
        }
        else {
            layers_0.getSubLayer(0).hide();
        }
    });

    $("#Dogs_Check").change(function() {
      var value = $(this).prop("checked") ? 'true' : 'false';
      if (value === "true") {
        layers_0.getSubLayer(1).show(); 
      }
      else {
        layers_0.getSubLayer(1).hide();
      }
    });

    $("#Birds_Check").change(function() {
      var value = $(this).prop("checked") ? 'true' : 'false';
      if (value === "true") {
        layers_0.getSubLayer(2).show();
      }
      else {
        layers_0.getSubLayer(2).hide();
      }
    });

    $("#Horses_Check").change(function() {
      var value = $(this).prop("checked") ? 'true' : 'false';
      if (value === "true") {
        layers_0.getSubLayer(3).show();
      }
      else {
        layers_0.getSubLayer(3).hide();
      }
    });

    $("#Goats_Check").change(function() {
        debugger
      var value = $(this).prop("checked") ? 'true' : 'false';
      if (value === "true") {
        layers_1.getSubLayer(0).show();
      }
      else {
        layers_1.getSubLayer(0).hide();
      }
    });

    $("#Lizards_Check").change(function() {
      var value = $(this).prop("checked") ? 'true' : 'false';
      if (value === "true") {
        //aler("layers.getSubLayer(4): " + layers.getSubLayer(4));
        layers_1.getSubLayer(1).show();
      }
      else {
        layers_1.getSubLayer(1).hide();
      }
    });

    $("#Rabbits_Check").change(function() {
      var value = $(this).prop("checked") ? 'true' : 'false';
      if (value === "true") {
        //aler("layers.getSubLayer(4): " + layers.getSubLayer(4));
        layers_1.getSubLayer(2).show();
      }
      else {
        layers_1.getSubLayer(2).hide();
      }
    });

    $("#Sheep_Check").change(function() {
      var value = $(this).prop("checked") ? 'true' : 'false';
      if (value === "true") {
        //aler("layers.getSubLayer(4): " + layers.getSubLayer(4));
        layers_1.getSubLayer(3).show();
      }
      else {
        layers_1.getSubLayer(3).hide();
      }
    });

  }

  var layerN = {};
  function main() {
    var map = L.map('map', { 
      zoomControl: true,
      center: [42.2, -71.8],
      zoom: 8
    });

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all//{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
   attribution: 'Mapbox <a href="http://mapbox.com/about/maps" target="_blank">Terms &amp; Feedback</a>'
}).addTo(map);

    // get the currently selected style  
    selectedStyle = $('li.selected').attr('id');

    cartodb.createLayer(map, 'http://massgis.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/ba5325b4-967d-11e4-83eb-0e9d821ea90d/viz.json')
    .addTo(map)
    .done(function(layers) {

        layers_0 = layers;

        cartodb.createLayer(map, 'http://massgis.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/1bb532f2-96a1-11e4-bcff-0e9d821ea90d/viz.json')
        .addTo(map)
        .done(function(layers) {

          layers_1 = layers;
          createSelector(layers);

        })
        .error(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

  }

  window.onload = main;
</script>
```

Hope his helps! :)